# How to prove: If $n \in N$, then $n^2=2\binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{1}$

Tags: proof-explanation, solution-verification, binomial-theorem

**Prove using a direct proof method: If $n \in N$, then $n^2=2\binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{1}$.**

I would assume that the proof uses the **Binomial Theorem**, however I don't know how to apply it in this context.

Perhaps it is something in regard to:

$$n^2 = (2n-n)^2$$
$$n^2 = \binom{n}{0}(2n)^n(-n)^0 + \binom{n}{1}(2n)^{n-1}(-n) + \binom{n}{2}(2n)^{n-2}n^2$$
$$n^2 = (2n)^n - n^2(2n)^n \frac{1}{(2n)} + \frac{n^3(n+1)}{2}(2n)^n \frac{1}{(2n)^2} $$
$$...$$

Comment: Use that $\binom{n}{2}$ is a simple quadratic in $n$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate, I'm not quite skillful in binomial coefficients :)

Comment: You can work out just from the definition that it's $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $2\binom n2=2\frac{n(n-1)}2=n^2-n.$

Comment: I downvoted....

Comment: @Surb Thank you for telling me. Why did you do that?

Comment: Because this is what I would give as a comment... (as several of your answer)

Comment: If I had learned how to answer from a comment, I would not have posted it as an answer. But I will not stop from posting answers (obtained by me) simply because someone else decided to post that answer as a comment.

Comment: you post very good answer, so it's not necessary to stop it ;-)

Comment: I downvoted because your level answer is very weak here

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your working: It should be:

$$n^2 = (2n-n)^2$$
$$n^2 = \binom{n}{0}(2n)^2(-n)^0 + \binom{n}{1}(2n)(-n) + \binom{n}{2}(2n)^{0}n^2$$